# apache 2.2.x trying to write a value into the request header?

Tags: apache, request-headers

I have the following set up in apache:

```
<Location /SASLogon/login>
Options +Includes
AuthType CAS
Require valid-user
RequestHeader append MirrorID "mirror 12"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
RewriteRule . - [E=RU:%1]                   
RequestHeader add X-Remote-User %{RU}e env=RU
RequestHeader add Authorization "Basic fgawegPXtICBLluzXerwertg"
</Location>
```

What I am trying to do on the web server is to see if the X-Remote_User variable is actually coming, though. Wireshark and ngrep don't seem to show the value.:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this allowed me to confirm it was written

RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "D:\SASConfig\Lev1\Web\WebServer\logs\rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9

Comment: Is this a comment to Joes answer?

Comment: no sorry it isn't I have JSP at my disposal (as well as java/jQuery) none of thiose were able to allow me to expose that response header . However this Apache logging directive did

Answer (score 0):

If you add a request header in the location tag, it will not be present in the network packet, i.e. the browser sending the request doesn't know about it.  It gets added *after* apache receives the request but before it starts to process the files to serve the page.  So you should be able to check from within a script at that location, such as with PHP's $_SERVER array.